# go-colly returning empty slice

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I am trying to scrape a website, but it seems my slice of products it's empty.

scraper.go:

```golang
package scraper

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/extensions"
)

type Product struct {
    name      string
    fullPrice string
    url       string
}

func Scraper(site string) []Product {

    products := []Product{}
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    replacer := strings.NewReplacer("R$", "", ",", ".")
    c.OnHTML("div#column-main-content", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fullPrice := e.ChildText("span.m7nrfa-0.eJCbzj.sc-ifAKCX.ANnoQ")
        product := Product{
            name:      e.ChildText("h2"),
            fullPrice: replacer.Replace(fullPrice),
            url:       e.ChildAttr("a.sc-1fcmfeb-2.iezWpY", "href"),
        }
        fmt.Println(product)
        products = append(products, product)
    })
    fmt.Println(products)

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
    })

    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "failed with response:", r.Request, "\nError:", err)
    })

    // Uses a random User-Agent in each request
    extensions.RandomUserAgent(c)

    c.Visit(site)
    return products
}
```

main.go:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/Antonio-Costa00/Go-Price-Monitor/scraper"

func main() {
    scraper.Scraper("https://sp.olx.com.br/?q=iphone%27")
}
```

product variable has an output, but the slice is empty.

slice output:

`[]`

I don't know if I am doing something wrong when appending the result to products slice.

Can someone help me to check if I am doing something wrong to return an empty slice?

Comment: Show how you print that output.

Comment: Sure. Products: `fmt.Println(products)` product: `fmt.Println(product)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Colly](https://go-colly.org) library does the scraping asynchronously, so when you print the `products` it is empty, but it will be filled in another `goroutine`. By using the `OnScraped` handler and printing the `products` there you should see it is filled.

```golang
package scraper

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"

        "github.com/gocolly/colly"
        "github.com/gocolly/colly/extensions"
)

type Product struct {
        name      string
        fullPrice string
        url       string
}

func Scraper(site string) []Product {
        products := []Product{}
        c := colly.NewCollector()
        replacer := strings.NewReplacer("R$", "", ",", ".")
        c.OnHTML("div#column-main-content", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
                fullPrice := e.ChildText("span.m7nrfa-0.eJCbzj.sc-ifAKCX.ANnoQ")
                product := Product{
                        name:      e.ChildText("h2"),
                        fullPrice: replacer.Replace(fullPrice),
                        url:       e.ChildAttr("a.sc-1fcmfeb-2.iezWpY", "href"),
                }
                fmt.Println(product)
                products = append(products, product)
        })

        c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
                fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
        })

        c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
                fmt.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "failed with response:", r.Request, "\nError:", err)
        })

        c.OnScraped(func(r *colly.Response) {
                fmt.Println(products)
        })

        // Uses a random User-Agent in each request
        extensions.RandomUserAgent(c)

        c.Visit(site)
        return products
}
```

Comment: +1 . Thank you so much! Justa  question: why sometimes I saw programs using colly not using the method OnScraped and getting the results?

Comment: You can use OnHTML for results too, you just need to pay attention to the gorutines concept.

Comment: In that case, if I don't wanna use the OnScraped method, would be possible to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a channel for notifying other components of your system that your variable is updated.